# webpack, CommonsChunkPlugin gives syntax error for generated files

Tags: lambda, webpack

I am using webpack to generate a vendor.js and main.js file using CommonsChunkPlugin.  I want all the node_modules that my app is using to go into the vendor.js file.  However the generated vendor.js and main.js file have syntax errors.  I'm actually writing a lambda function for AWS.  This is my webpack.config file.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/app'
    },
    watch: false,
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: module => module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            'config/shoppingPathsSAM.yaml'
        ])
    ],
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    }
}
```

my .babelrc file has the following

```
{ "presets": [ [ "env" ] ] }
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of the syntax error that you get, the `node` version, `babel` version, and other relevant details.

Comment: Also, where are you getting the syntax errors? In AWS Lambda or on your local?

Answer (score 0):

You misconfigured your babel config. It may not have been configured to output code that is compatible with Node 6.10 (or whatever node version you use).

To make `babel` compile your code to be `nodejs6.10`-compatible, you can use this in your `.babelrc`.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "6.10"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: my .babelrc has the following

{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env"
        ]
    ]
}

Comment: You should include that in your question.

Comment: What's your `node` version?

Comment: its 6.5, but still irrespective of that, if I just open up the bundled file in VS Code its showing a syntax error for both the vendor and main files.

Comment: Of course, there are syntax errors because you're not targeting `node 6.5` in your babel config.

Comment: Also, you should be running node 6.10 if you're developing for AWS Lambda so that what you have in your machine is the same as what is running it in production.

Comment: I changed the .babelrc file to what is given here, still I get the syntax errors.  If its helpful, I can post the finally generated code, but its a bit big.

Comment: @tmpdev You still get the errors because you still used node 6.5 or maybe VS Code uses a different node version.

Comment: I boiled it down to CommonsChunkPlugin.  Basically when I use CommonsChunkPlugin the bundle file that gets generated contains the following at the root (this is the line which causes the syntax error)

(function(e, a) { for(var i in a) e[i] = a[i]; }(exports, exports.ids = [0];

Whereas if I do not use it, the following is generated (no syntax error)

(function(e, a) { for(var i in a) e[i] = a[i]; }(exports, /******/ (function(modules)

Any ideas anyone?  I also pasted the code on Esprima and I get the same syntax error

Comment: @tmpdev You're supposed to include it in your question. Not as a comment here.

Comment: I saw an article saying CommonsChunkPlugin is for browser based and since I'm using this for a node environment it will not work? just wanted to confirm.  If I cannot use it then how do I split the code into two different chunks in a node environment?

Comment: Why would you want to split it into chunks? It's useful in the browser because they can get downloaded separately but in Node, it's better to keep them as one compiled file.

Comment: I prefer to organize it that way, plus if I need to make any change on the Lambda console, then its easier for me to do it since I have a separate file containing all the vendor code and the main file will be much smaller.